# Treating a forced downcast to 'SCNView' as optional will never produce 'nil'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, downcast

Starting with swift 4.2, an error appears. In previous versions the code works fine (swift 3, 4). How to write this code correctly now?
[swift4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDi9p.png)
[swift4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASzHG.png)

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
var scene: SCNScene!
var scnView: SCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupScene()
    setupView()
}

func setupScene() {
    scene = SCNScene()
}

func setupView() {
    scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of force downcasting, use optional downcasting.
If `self.view` can't be downcasted as `SCNView` it'll return `nil`

```
func setupView() {
  scnView = self.view as? SCNView
  scnView.scene = scene
}
```

You can also handle failure like this:

```
func setupView() {
  if let scnView = self.view as? SCNView {
    scnView.scene = scene
  }
  else {
    // self.view couldn't be cast as SCNView, handle failure
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an instance of [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7906), caused by the thing you are assigning to, `scnView`, being an (implicitly unwrapped) optional, and you are using `as!`. It seems to be suggesting that since you are assigning to an optional, you *could* just use `as?` which produces an optional instead, and doesn't crash.

Assuming that you are sure that `self.view` is an `SCNView` (because you have set it in the storyboard, for example), and you want it to fail-fast when it is somehow *not* `SCNView`, you can silence the warning by adding brackets:

```
scnView = (self.view as! SCNView)
```